# How to use packages available for MongoDB on GitHub?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Am a new user of MonogoDB n Nodejs. Building a simple product catalogue. Trying to import CSV file contents to mongodb. I got Syntax error:: Unexpected identifier error: Is there any way to resolve this?
I am curious to know about using ya-csv package available on Git. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you pulling the source from github directly into your project? Or are you actually installing via npm? `npm install ya-csv`

Comment: How are you using the package? Please add the relevant source to your question. It could be anything causing that error.

Comment: Sorry i wanted to try ya-csv. But general import statement worked. @WiredPrairie

Comment: npm install ya-csv worked :) @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
npm install ya-csv  //install package

//Put this code in your .js file

var csv = require("ya-csv");
var validRows        = [];
var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader("/csv/file.csv", {columnsFromHeader:true,'separator': ',' , encoding: "utf8"});

reader.addListener('data', function(data) {       //if rows are in correct format then it will push into array
    if(data){
        validRows.push(data);            
    }
});

reader.addListener('end', function(){          //this method will be called after reading all csv rows   
   validRows.forEach(function(data){         
           //console.log(data.name);           //get your data like this
        });
});

reader.addListener('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);                           //if any error occurred        
});
```

For further detail please follow this link

https://github.com/koles/ya-csv